# Зачем нужны ( ) в RegEx?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не как не могу понять как использовать и зачем нужны ( ) в регулярках. Может кто то подсказать и привести не большой пример.

Comment: Это группы, вот норм видос где объясняют https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8_DQjnALSo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Находить, вычленять определенные группы символов из строк. Задач может быть множество.

Вот к примеру найти все числа, которые начинаются с "привет", заканчиваются на "лет", а посередине могут быть любые числа. Вот нужно все эти числа найти.

```
привет100лет а может привет80лет а может и привет666лет
```

регулярка

```
/привет([0-9]+)лет/
```

в итоге

```
preg_match_all('/привет([0-9]+)лет/', 'привет100лет а может привет80лет а может и привет666лет', $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match[0].'<br/>';
}
```

выведет

```
100
80
666
```

---

Без выделения группы регулярное выражение выдавало бы цельный результат, типа

```
привет100лет
привет80лет
привет666лет
```

---

А вот регулярка вычленения телефонных номеров из строки:

```
/\(?  (\d{3})?  \)?  (?(1)  [\-\s] ) \d{3}-\d{4}/x
```

которая из строки

```
Звоните 555-1212 или 1-800-555-1212
```

достанет группы:

```
555-1212
800-555-1212
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Сохраняющие круглые скобки: (…) и \1, \2, …**

Стандартные круглые скобки обычно выполняют две функции: группировку и сохранение. Они почти всегда включаются в выражения
в виде (…), но в ряде диалектов используется запись `\(…\)`.

**Сохраняющие скобки идентифицируются по порядковому номеру открывающей скобки от левого края выражения**.

Если в диалекте поддерживаются обратные ссылки,
то на текст, совпавший с подвыражением в круглых скобках, можно
ссылаться в том же регулярном выражении при помощи метасимволов
**\1**, **\2** и т. д.

**Чаще всего круглые скобки применяются для извлечения данных из
строки**.